# Bookmark all open tabs in mobile safari

Tags: mobile-safari, bookmarks, tabs

I've got an iPhone with ~500 open tabs (500 is the limit). I'd like to bookmark all of the tabs so I can review/read them later on other non Apple devices and potentially in non-apple browsers.

Is there any app or solution (like a pinboard client) that will allow me to bookmark and close those tabs in mobile safari then, at a later time, view the bookmarks in another browser or on a desktop?

Comment: This would be an interesting pinboard app (or custom client) feature request, pin all bookmarks in a folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tyler Brook, the article you link as a solution is for a computer type of device and not an iPhone or mobile version of the browser. The mobile version has a more limited menu.
 I have the same question and am hitting the same wall.
So far I have to email my self links to get the open pages to a non-mobile device(with a bigger screen for my old eyes ).

The iOS 13 update is testing a new function to do exactly what you seek.

- https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/bookmark-multiple-open-tabs-safari-ios/